# Angular2 router navigate in ngOnInit

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using a service data structure *SharedDataService* to transfer data between components.
Now, if the data structure is not set because e.g. F5 is pressed, I would like to jump back to another component by using router.navigate in ngOnInit.

I have nested a child component inside a parent component and both have the logic to check for a valid data structure and navigate if not present.

In another case the child component is used alone and they should navigate in this case to a different location.

The problem is that ngOnInit of the child is called despite I route in the parent.
Then in the child ngOnInit the following error occurs:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
at getPath (create_url_tree.ts:135)
at createNewSegment (create_url_tree.ts:221)
at updateSegment (create_url_tree.ts:163)
at updateSegmentChildren (create_url_tree.ts:174)
at Object.createUrlTree (create_url_tree.ts:28)
at Router.createUrlTree (router.ts:221)
at Router.navigate (router.ts:263)
at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (conceptversion.component.ts:48)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrSetError (Subscriber.ts:249)
at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:193)
```

I tried to create a plunker, but the problem is that I don't know how to include the router from "@angular/router". Maybe you could already see what I am trying to do.

http://plnkr.co/edit/oyrSbW6jYhVOsjnp0MHv?p=preview

Comment: Please provide the code that demonstrates what you tried and allows to reproduce. A Plunker to reproduce would be great as well.

Comment: Since there isn't much information I'll just say I had the same error when my routerLink was badly defined. Used brackets while the value was just a string e.g ```<a [routerLink]="/path">``` instead of ```<a routerLink="/path">```.

Comment: I've forgot to check param for existence. But IMO it's still strange that ngOnInit of child is called after navigate in parent.

Comment: Why do you think it is weird? `ngOnInit()` is called by Angulars change detection. If you do something (sync code) during change detection why would you expect other successive code to silently stop executing. I think the problem here is that you call `router.navigate()` in `ngOnInit()`